# How to implement two OnClickListeners on RecyclerView item click?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I'm quite confused since I need to use two OnClickListeners for two different needs.
I have a Recyclerview which once any item of his, once pressed, needs to change and I've implemented that successfully using `OnBindViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener`

Now, I want that very same click to update my BottomAppBar and for that, I added an interface to my ItemHolder class. The issue is that now I once I click, due to the interface (I guess) nothing happens.

I know it might be a bit complicated to understand my situation so I add the following code to help with that:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MultiViewTypeAdapter.IClickListener {
```

has this function:

```
 @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        int type = adapter.getItemViewType(position);
        if (type == 0) {
            bar.setFabAlignmentMode(BottomAppBar.FAB_ALIGNMENT_MODE_END);
            bar.replaceMenu(R.menu.bab_menu_chosen_project);
            fab.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_message_white_24dp));
        }
        else{
            bar.setFabAlignmentMode(BottomAppBar.FAB_ALIGNMENT_MODE_CENTER);
            bar.replaceMenu(R.menu.bab_menu_primary);
            fab.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_reply_black_24dp));
        }

    }
```

the interface at the adapter looks like this:

```
public interface IClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }
```

what I'm currently doing on 
`public static class SelectedProjectItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {`
is this:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listener.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
        }
```

however, what I want to run is what I'm doing on

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int listPosition) {
```

is:

```
((SelectedProjectItemHolder) holder).itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dataSet.remove(listPosition);
                        dataSet.add(listPosition, unselectedCards.get(listPosition));
                        notifyItemChanged(listPosition);
                    }
                });
```

I wish two things will happen from one click - the item on Recyclerview will change using the last piece of code I described, and the menu in my MainActivity will change using the first piece of code I described.

THANKS HELPERS!

Comment: what's your logic Distinguishing two onClick? i mean when first one works and when next one?

Comment: @Mr.AF, these 2 things should be done together but one is handled by activity and the other one by RV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove below code from RecyclerView.ViewHolder

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    listener.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
}
```

And add listner event in "itemView" click as below:

```
((SelectedProjectItemHolder) holder).itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if(listener != null){
                            listener.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
                        }
                        dataSet.remove(listPosition);
                        dataSet.add(listPosition, unselectedCards.get(listPosition));
                        notifyItemChanged(listPosition);
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your BottomBar width same (unique) click using UIHandler or MainLoop,with which you can access the UI from your adapter.
on your OnCreate:

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 //.....
Handler uiHandle = new Handler(getMainLooper()){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            Bundle b = (Bundle) msg.obj;
            int p = b.getInt("position");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Change here your BottomBAR",     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    };
```

.. and in your adapter ...

```
 yourobjectclick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

           // example: first change color of my object that I have clicked
                ((TextView)v).setTextColor( mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_100));
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
               //i can store the position about click and
                bundle.putInt("position",position);

                Message message = handler.obtainMessage();
                message.obj = bundle;
                // i have access tu User Interface objects from here

           // next change my bottombar sending a message to UI
           handler.sendMessage(message);
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "onClick: su -> "+tvBikeName.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```